# Php mail() and Header("Location: 'url') causes an 'infinite' loop?

Tags: php, email, header

Hi I used a tutorial for learning the moderately difficult header information required to send an email with an optional attachment in php.  I modified it a little bit and it was working as I expected, until I changed it to match exactly the tutorial for testing purposes. As soon as I tested it I checked my email a few seconds later and 21 emails had already been sent to me. I deleted the file from the server right away and closed the page. I am wondering what exactly caused this behavior.

Immediately after the mail() function I set a redirect to the page I wanted.

```
if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
    header("Location: $redirectUrl");
    exit;       
}
```

where $header is half a page long. Is it the header() function causing it? The page just says page is taking too long to redirect. Do I have a problem with escaped / non-escaped characters? I call the function only one time and it is not included within any kind of for loop or do while. The page itself is not included anywhere else.

Comment: Well, what's `$redirectUrl`? There's nothing wrong with the code as it is now, unless `$redirectUrl` causes `header()` to redirect you back to the same script.

Comment: It just redirects to a separate page on the same site but different directory.

Comment: PHP's `mail()` function is awful. I would *strongly* recommend using a decent mail class like [phpMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/). It will make your life easier, no matter what you're using `mail()` for.

Comment: @Matt Is it possible that `$redirectUrl` is actually empty? If that happens, you can have unpredictable behavior with the redirect. Try setting it to a hardcoded value and see what happens.

Comment: @NullUserException Hmm... no, but maybe it's out of scope? I have it defined at the top of my script, and then I call my mail_with_attachment function(), where the mail() function itelsef is inside, and I didn't pass the variable to the function. Is that why?

Comment: Yes, and when I said "actually empty" being out of scope is one of the possible reasons why it would be empty.

Answer (score 0):

NullUserException brought up a good point. The variable was out of scope. A very simple change fixed the script. Originally the variable was declared outside the function, and not visible within the function.